# how do i set default char set to null in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi All in phpinfo page I find the charset is UTF-8.
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8 
I want to remove the charset to null witout changing in php.ini file is it possible.

Comment: have you try header("Content-Type text/html; charset=ANY_THING_THAT_NOT_STANDARD_CHRSET") ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "null charset".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the privileges to do so, you can [override INI settings](https://www.php.net/ini-set) on a per-script basis. Otherwise you can simply [output an overriding header](https://www.php.net/header): `header("Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");` or include it directly in your HTML output as `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />`, obviously replacing ISO-8859-1 with whatever you want.

Comment: He wanted to be nothing, no utf8 nor iso-8859-1. It's strange to me, but anyway...

Answer (score 3):

You can set on top of your file `ini_set("default_charset", "");`

Comment: Or .htaccess >>> php_value default_charset null

Answer (score 3):

A "null charset" is the same as ISO-8859-1 according to [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

> When no explicit charset    parameter
>   is provided by the sender, media
>   subtypes of the "text"    type are
>   defined to have a default charset
>   value of "ISO-8859-1" when    received
>   via HTTP.

Setting the charset to ISO-8859-1 is therefore the same as not setting any charset at all. However, since Google Chrome implements this wrong (they default to UTF-8) you should really consider to explicitly set the charset to ISO-8859-1 (or whichever charset you are using).

Comment: This is theoretically the correct answer; note that due to a myriad of sloppy webpages, this is not entirely true in practice; most browsers do some sort of charset sniffing to determine the probable charset.

Comment: Most browsers get it wrong when they try to sniff the charset, so the best bet is still to set it explicitly.

Comment: It's indeed best to set it explicitly; but the majority of sniffing actually gets it *right* (so the user doesn't even notice). However, when the heuristic fails, the results are highly visible, which leads to the assumption "it usually fails". Yes, it's a last-resort fallback measure, and yes, the server *should* know and advertise what charset it's using. Alas, there are still broken sites - and users perceive this as broken *browser* instead.

Comment: I've seen numerous sites where the browsers guess for UTF-8 when it should be ISO-8859-1. I consider that a broken browser.

Comment: If a browser defaults to an encoding that's not ISO-8859-1, it is also broken. What I meant are sites that send conflicting data: no charset specified in headers, one charset specified in meta tags, different charest actually used. That used to be quite common, fortunately it's slowly going away.

Answer (score 1):

You can output a header to set it:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=YOUR_CHARSET');
```

If you don't set a charset in this header, the browser will try to guess on its own which is not recommended. Most of the times in western countries that guess would be ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15.

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html'); // note the absence of charset=
```

Note however, that there's nothing such as "null charset", there's always some kind of mapping between the bytes and characters (even ASCII is such a *mapping*, not The Natural Order Of Things). What you're doing is telling the browser "I don't know what charset this is, just make a guess" - which may or may not choose the actual charset.